# Talend tInputFileDelimited component java.lang.NumberFormatException for CSV file

Tags: etl, talend, numberformatexception

As a beginner to TOS for BD, I am trying to read two csv files in Talend OS, i have inferred the metadata schema from the same CSV file, and setup the first row to be header, and delimiter as comma (,)
In my code:
The tMap will read the csv file, and do a lookup on another csv file, and generate two output files passed and reject records.

But while running the job i am getting below error.
**Couldn't parse value for column 'Product_ID' in 'row1', value is '4569,Laptop,10'. Details: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "4569,Laptop,10"**

**I believe it is considering entire row as one string to be the value for "Product_ID" column**

I don't know why that is happening when i have set the delimiter and row separator correctly.

[Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0yKx.jpg)

I can see no rows are going from the first tInputFileDelimited due to above error.

[Job Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfaZs.jpg)

[Input component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1ZtE.jpg)

Any idea what else can i check?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is anybody supposed to answer this without knowing what your code does? Please [edit] your question and post your code as a [mcve].

Comment: @Robert: Added minimal description of the code, and relevant screenshots, This should clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your last screenshot, you can see that the `Field separator` of your `tFileInputDelimited_1` is `;` and not `,`.
I believe that you haven't set up your component to use the metadata you created for your csv file.
So you need to configure the component to use the metadata you've created by selecting `Repository` under `Property Type`, and selecting the delimited file metadata.